# How to output line if no exception was thrown?

Tags: ruby

I am looping through a file, and if the line contains only numbers I want to output the line.

```
puts line if Integer(line)
```

How could I catch the exception and then not display the line, is this possible with a single line of code? i.e. one liner

Answer (score 1):

In ruby `rescue` can be on one line. This is a bad idea, read more here https://robots.thoughtbot.com/don-t-inline-rescue-in-ruby

Now that you know you shouldn't.

`puts line if Integer(line) rescue nil`

Where the object to the right of the `rescue` is the return value of the line if ANY error is raised.

Comment: This is one of those situations where I do think inline rescue is more-or-less acceptable, mostly because the Ruby doesn't come with the variant of `Integer()` we really want, `Integer?()`, that returns false instead of raising an exception when passed inappropriate input. You could define it yourself, but if you define it in terms of `Integer()`, you're still ultimately using exceptions for non-exceptional circumstances. I'd love to see `Integer?()` as a built-in.

Comment: @philomory I do tend to agree, but regardless the inline rescue is inappropriate. Take the ruby approach, and write a method.
`
    def integer?(thing)
      Integer(thing)
    rescue Argument
        false
    end

`

Comment: Actually, per the article you linked, the example you gave doesn't work as written; your answer will _return_ ArgumentError in case of an exception, it doesn't only catch ArgumentError.

Comment: Hmm this is interesting, and hence the reason of that article. 
`puts "a" if Integer("a") rescue ArgumentError` does indeed return the error, but the if branch DOES NOT run. So the above code does work.  My understanding is the the interpreter is wrapping the entire block to the left as `(puts "a" if Integer("a")) rescue ArgumentError` so YES it does return `ArgumentError` but it also does function as expected. Not running the `if` branch to the left of the rescue keyword. TIL

Comment: Right, but if some _other_ exception is raised, it still rescues the exception and returns ArgumentError. Of course, for this precise line of code, there is no other exception descended from StandardError that could actually be produced (SystemExit, MemoryError, etc, would not be caught anyway). But putting an exception type after the inline rescue is extra-misleading; it's even worse than `rescue nil`, because it _looks like_ exception filtering, but it's not.

Comment: AHHH I see your point, yes 100% editing my answer to point towards `rescue nil`.